How to make an old laravel query more readable in laravel
How can I make this more readable in laravel elequent? How can I get rid of CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(...))?
            DB::table('games AS g')
            ->select('g.*')
            ->join('results AS r', 'g.id', '=', 'r.game_id')
            ->join('users_teams AS ut', 'ut.user_id', '=', 'r.user_id')
            ->whereRaw("((g.min_max_algorithm_time IS NULL) OR (r.time >= CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(g.min_max_algorithm_time, '-', 1) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AND r.time <= CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(g.min_max_algorithm_time, '-', -1) AS DECIMAL(10,2))))")
            ->whereRaw("((g.min_max_algorithm_score IS NULL) OR (r.score >= CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(g.min_max_algorithm_score, '-', 1) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AND r.score <= CAST(SUBSTRING_INDEX(g.min_max_algorithm_score, '-', -1) AS DECIMAL(10,2))))")
            ->where('ut.team_id', '=', $teamId)
            ->where('ut.is_player', '=', '1')
            ->groupBy('g.id')
            ->get()
            ->toArray();



You can make it cleaner with Eloquent models and relations between them: https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/eloquent-relationships

Please publish the datatypes for r.time, g.min_max_algorithm_time,r.score and g.min_max_algorithm_score together with sample data.
